# Allowing a background to overflow?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a background such as the below:

[image]

Trouble is I want to set the width of the containing box to only cover up to the end of the white areas & hence the shadow should "overflow". I don't want to use an out container or padding as I am trying to avoid extra width; if the background overflows then the browser isn't going to create horizontal; scrollbars for this and that's exactly what I want.

Is there any way I can accomplish this or will I be forced to use the full width?

Answer (score 0):

Backgrounds on `<body>` don't affect the scrollbars, so depending on what you need the shadow for you might be able to do something similar to this;

```
body {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftW5z.png) no-repeat center top;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 1014px; /* inner space of shadow image */
    margin: 35px auto; /* 35px matches size of top shadow */
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gjsxn/2/

You can likely achieve the same effect with another container and use of min-width and overflow hidden.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I have another image set as the body backgrouund, but you just gave me an idea to perhaps include that as part of the background image; not really ideal though TBH.